# pexpect and shell meta characters (>, |, or *)

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect, metacharacters

I am pretty confused right now.

**pexpect** [documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) states the following:

```
Remember that Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters such as
redirect, pipe, or wild cards (>, |, or *). This is a common mistake.
If you want to run a command and pipe it through another command then
you must also start a shell. For example::

child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "ls -l | grep LOG > log_list.txt"')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

However I am looking at some old code that uses `|` and `*` in `pexpect.sendline(some command | grep 'something')`.
So I started to test these command and they all seem to work. It is also worth mentioning that I am not using a modified pexpect module, it is plain old pexpect for python.

How come? why does **pexpect** mention that **meta characters does not work**, when it obviously does so?

Comment: What does the code pass to `pexpect.sendline()`?

Comment: @ecatmur, machine specific command, but usually with | grep after the command or | and *. see revised code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pexpect.spawn` doesn't interpret shell meta characters, but whatever's running inside pexpect (presumably a shell) clearly does:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
child.sendline('echo hello | cat')
```

pexpect is just passing the string to the child process; it's not interpreting it.

Comment: the documentation is really unclear then, since it say "Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters"

Comment: @theAlse right, pexpect isn't interpreting the meta characters; it's passing them straight to the child process unchanged.  The child process is interpreting them.

Comment: but I see another thing, you are actually starting a bash! But in my case I connect to an embedded machine that does not provide a bash, it is just a shell which can interpret some special command received via ssh/telnet plus some other commands such as grep (it does not have a /bash).

Comment: @theAlse bash is just an example of a shell; your embedded machine is running a shell.